# Rendering once from getInitialState, and again after componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This might be a novice question, but I wonder why React.js renders the component twice - once when the `getInitialState()` lifecycle method is called, and once after `componentDidMount()`.

What are the specific cases where you might want to render something before `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: By "render" you mean execute the render method?

Comment: yup, i meant executing the render method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It only renders once by default, but if you put setState methods in the didmount method, the component will re-render. Post some code if you want us to debug it.

Comment: ah, it was re-rendered by a higher level component, but by itself. Thanks for the clarification!